# Navigating using SSH

Tags: netrw, ssh

I know one can use `vim scp://host/path/to/file` to edit locally remote files then update the remote machine when saving (`:w`).
However I would like to know if it's possible to navigate through directories using ssh (or if there's a plugin to do that)

NERDTree doesn't support it, and when viming into a folder, although netrw allow me to navigate into directories, opening a file doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops forgot I had this question opened !

So the problem was that, with the netrw version I had (packaged with vim-gnome on Debian Jessie), modifying a file from the explorer (through ssh) would not use the correct URI (from memory, the '@' in the 'user@host' was missing).
It opened an empty file (because it didn't find anything) but it still saved the new file using the good URI (effectively overwriting the original file).

@user21497's answer also helped me though because I never found that 'new file' shortcut, which is quite handy because using ':e' creates the file locally.

Finally, [this question helped me navigate better using netrw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160499/go-to-back-directory-browsing-after-opening-file-in-vim) (getting back to the explorer after opening a file using :Ex)

Thanks for your help guys !

Answer (score 18):

Instead of pointing Vim/Netrw to a file:

```
scp://host/path/file
```

point it to a directory:

```
scp://host/path/
```

This gives you the same listing and the same shortcuts as if you were browsing your machine.

Comment: have you tried this when remoting from your `Unix` machine to access  folders on a Windows machine.. I just tried `vim  scp://user@10.1.4.4//C:/Users/user/Desktop/tmp/`, and it just gave me a blank screen, with the error `'ls' is not recognized as an internal or external command` when I try: `vim  scp://user@10.1.4.4//C:/Users/user/Desktop/tmp/filename`.. it works fine.

Comment: From this it seems that `vim` is issuing a command `ls`, when it logs into the remote computer.. and because its a windows computer.. there is no `ls`.. and the command fails. Is it possible for vim to traverse `windows` directories over ssh using `netrw` plugin or something else ? I using `VIM 8.1`

Comment: Please note that **the trailing slash after `scp://host//path/` is necessary** for this to work; otherwise, vim will try to open the path as a regular file, which will load blank.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "notify new file"; if you want to create a new file, when browsing via scp://hostname/directory, just press "%" like you would when in a local directory to create a new file.  See :help netrw-%.  You may create a directory using d (:help netrw-d).  If you want to modify an already existing file, select it with your cursor atop the filename in the netrw display and press `<cr>` (there are other selection methods, too, including v, o, t, etc).  See :help netrw-quickmap for an overview on this.  I've just tried this and did not get an empty file (when pre-existing).  A new file, of course, will be empty.